# word warp attribute "break-word" doesn't work for my text

Tags: css

I have this css code :

```
.SubjectCell{
width: 300px;    
padding-left: 3em;
padding-right: 2em;
color: black;
font-size: 20px;
word-wrap:break-word;  }
```

I applied this class on a table cell inside a table in my datalist:

```
<td class="SubjectCell">
<br />
<p>SOMEVERYVERYVERYVERYVERYVERYVERYVERYlongword</p>
</td>
```

but it doesn't break the words at all  !! any help please?

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
table {
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/95pa4/)

Answer (score 1):

Add `table-layout: fixed;` to the table.

**jsfiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/P44X6/